# Override two onBackPressed method in the same activity

Tags: android

On back pressed the previous page must appear on exit popup dialog should appear, I've used two `onBackpressed` methods in the same activity.  error: method `onBackPressed()` is already defined in class `MainActivity`. How can i override `onBackPressed` method or destroy app on exit.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar superProgressBar;
    ImageView superImageView;
    WebView superWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        superProgressBar = findViewById( R.id.pg );
        superWebView = findViewById( R.id.wv );
        superImageView = findViewById( R.id.im );
        superProgressBar.setMax( 100 );
        superWebView.loadUrl( "https://www.google.com" );
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
        superWebView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() );
        superWebView.setWebChromeClient( new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged( view, newProgress );
                superProgressBar.setProgress( newProgress );
            }

            @RequiresApi( api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                super.onReceivedTitle( view, title );
                Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setTitle( title );
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view, Bitmap icon) {
                super.onReceivedIcon( view, icon );
                superImageView.setImageBitmap( icon );
            }
        } );

    }

    @Override

    public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
                AlertDialog.Builder( MainActivity.this );
        builder.setMessage( "" );
        builder.setCancelable( true );
        builder.setNegativeButton( "", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                } );
        builder.setPositiveButton( "", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        finish();
                    }
                } );
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate( R.menu.super_menu, menu );
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if ( item.getItemId() == R.id.ref ) {
            superWebView.reload();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if ( superWebView.canGoBack() ) {
            superWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create method like below

```
private void showExitPopup() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setNegativeButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            finishAffinity();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Then override onBackPressed method like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (superWebView.canGoBack()) {
    superWebView.goBack();
}
else {
    showExitPopup();
   }
}
```

Comment: worked seamlessly thank you.( correction: showExitPopup(); )